# Error creating bean sessionFactory

Tags: java, hibernate, spring

I am integrating Spring with Hibernate. However, when I run the application I get an error like:

> Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [resources/spring.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to get the default Bean Validation factory

My spring.xml looks like:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

<bean id="myDataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/3encult" />
    <property name="password" value="3encult" />
    <property name="username" value="3encult" />
</bean>

<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="myDataSource" />
    <property name="mappingResources">
        <list>
            <value>
                resources/User.hbm.xml
                <!-- Project.hbm.xml ProjCF.hbm.xml Task.hbm.xml TaskCF.hbm.xml Category.hbm.xml 
                    TaskEstimation.hbm.xml ProjectEstimation.hbm.xml Parameter.hbm.xml StatisticTool.hbm.xml 
                    Report.hbm.xml -->
            </value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>
            <!-- Especificamos el valor minimo del pool de conexiones -->
            <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.minPoolSize">5</prop>
            <!-- Especificamos el valor maximo del pool de conexiones -->
            <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.maxPoolSize">20</prop>
            <!-- El tiempo de vida de cada conexion del pool. -->
            <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">600</prop>

        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="myUserDAO" class="main.java.com.gwt.app.server.User">
    <property name="sesionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>
</beans>
```

And the injection in class User is:

```
ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(new String[]{"resources/spring.xml"});

public void setSesionFactory(SessionFactory sesionFactory){
    this.sesionFactory = sesionFactory;
    this.sesion = this.sesionFactory.openSession();
}
```

The stacktrace is:

```
Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [resources/spring.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is    org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to get the default Bean Validation factory
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [resources/spring.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to get the default Bean Validation factory
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1420)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:563)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:900)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:455)
at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:93)
at main.java.com.gwt.app.server.User.<init>(User.java:16)
at main.java.com.gwt.app.server.GreetingServiceImpl.greetServer(GreetingServiceImpl.java:20)
at main.java.com.gwt.app.client.Main.main(Main.java:10)
 Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to get the default Bean Validation factory
at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.BeanValidationActivator.applyDDL(BeanValidationActivator.java:127)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.applyBeanValidationConstraintsOnDDL(Configuration.java:1677)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.applyConstraintsToDDL(Configuration.java:1627)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1418)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildMappings(Configuration.java:1348)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:717)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.AbstractSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractSessionFactoryBean.java:211)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1479)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1417)
... 14 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.BeanValidationActivator.applyDDL(BeanValidationActivator.java:118)
... 22 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to build the default ValidatorFactory
at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.TypeSafeActivator.getValidatorFactory(TypeSafeActivator.java:383)
at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.TypeSafeActivator.applyDDL(TypeSafeActivator.java:109)
... 27 more
Caused by: javax.validation.ValidationException: Unable to find a default provider
at javax.validation.Validation$GenericBootstrapImpl.configure(Validation.java:264)
at javax.validation.Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory(Validation.java:111)
at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.TypeSafeActivator.getValidatorFactory(TypeSafeActivator.java:380)
... 28 more
```

Build path contains the following libraries:

```
hibernate3.jar
org.springframework.aop-3.1.0.M1.jar
org.springframework.asm-3.1.0.M1.jar
org.springframework.aspects-3.1.0.M1.jar
org.springframework.beans-3.1.0.M1.jar
org.springframework.context-3.1.0.M1.jar
org.springframework.context.support-3.1.0.M1.jar
org.springframework.core-3.1.0.M1.jar
org.springframework.expression-3.1.0.M1.jar
org.springframework.instrument-3.1.0.M1.jar
org.springframework.instrument.tomcat-3.1.0.M1.jar
org.springframework.jdbc-3.1.0.M1.jar
org.springframework.jms-3.1.0.M1.jar
org.springframework.orm-3.1.0.M1.jar
org.springframework.oxm-3.1.0.M1.jar
org.springframework.transaction-3.1.0.M1.jar
```

I am not using validation. It is the reason of not include the validation jar.

I do not know what happens, I would like someone could help me.

Thanks!

Comment: can you please post more of stacktrace

Comment: Which version of Hibernate are you using?

Comment: can you list the hibernate and spring jar on your classpath.

Comment: org.springframework.aop-3.1.0.M1.jar
org.springframework.asm-3.1.0.M1.jar
org.springframework.aspects-3.1.0.M1.jar
org.springframework.beans-3.1.0.M1.jar
org.springframework.context-3.1.0.M1.jar
org.springframework.context.support-3.1.0.M1.jar
org.springframework.core-3.1.0.M1.jar
org.springframework.expression-3.1.0.M1.jar
org.springframework.instrument-3.1.0.M1.jar
org.springframework.instrument.tomcat-3.1.0.M1.jar
org.springframework.jdbc-3.1.0.M1.jar
org.springframework.jms-3.1.0.M1.jar
org.springframework.orm-3.1.0.M1.jar
org.springframework.oxm-3.1.0.M1.jar and hibernate3.jar

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Hibernate raises an exception:  `throw new HibernateException( "Unable to get the default Bean Validation factory", e);` if it can not access Bean Validation Framework (BeanValidationActivator).

So I guess the problem is that the Validation jars are missing.

For Maven:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.2.GA</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 5):

Try adding following maven dependencies (or download the JAR's if you don't use Maven):

- [Hibernate Validator](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-validator/4.0.2.GA)
- [Javax Validation](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.validation)

Other dependencies might also be required (consider to use [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html) if you are not yet, to avoid issues like this)

Answer (score 0):

Try once by adding this line to your hibernate.cfg.xml file

```
<property name="javax.persistence.validation.mode" value="none"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have updated the Tomcat version from 8.5 to 9.0, it worked for me.