# HibernateException: Unable to get the default Bean Validation factory with JRE 7

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I am trying to write a simple program to integrate GWT, SPRING and Hibernate. But when I try to run the program as a web Application using eclipse, I get the exception as mentioned above. I have added the code below for reference. Any kind of help will be great. Thanks in advance.

applicationContext.xml File:

```
 <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.5.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">

      <bean id="propertyConfigurer"
       class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
      <property name="location" value="jdbc.properties" />
       </bean>

        <bean id="validationFactory" class="javax.validation.Validation"
          factory-method="buildDefaultValidatorFactory" />
      <bean id="hibernateTemplate" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate">
          <property name="sessionFactory">
         <ref local="sessionFactory" />
      </property>
         </bean>
    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.landiskart" />
    <aop:aspectj-autoproxy />

    <!-- Session Factory -->
       <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
      <property name="dataSource"><ref local="dataSource"/></property>
      <property name="mappingResources">
         <list>
            <value>com/landiskart/server/persistence/User.hbm.xml</value>
           </list>
      </property>
      <property name="hibernateProperties">
         <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">
              org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
            </prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">
               true
            </prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">
               create
            </prop>

         </props>
      </property>
   </bean>

      <!-- DataSource -->
     <bean id="dataSource"     class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
         <property name="driverClassName">
            <value>${database.driver}</value>
        </property>
        <property name="url">
         <value>${database.url}</value>
      </property>
     <property name="username">
         <value>${database.user}</value>
      </property>
      <property name="password">
         <value>${database.password}</value>
      </property>
   </bean>
      <!-- switches on the transactional behavior-->
     <tx:annotation-driven />

       <!-- a PlatformTransactionManager is still required -->
       <bean id="transactionManager"      class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">     
  <!-- (this dependency is defined somewhere else) -->
  <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
  </bean>
</beans>
```

I have already the jars as mentioned in the link:
[Error creating bean sessionFactory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6054692/error-creating-bean-sessionfactory)

ie. the validation-api-1.0.0.GA.jar & hibernate-validator-4.0.2.Final.jar

Initial few lines of the stacktrace looks like:

```
Starting Jetty on port 0
  [WARN] failed context
  javax.servlet.ServletException:   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:    Error creating bean with name 'hibernateTemplate' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB- INF/applicationContext.xml]:   Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while  setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name  '  'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]:  Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException:  Unable to get the default Bean Validation factory
   at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:437)
   at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.doStart(ServletHolder.java:256)
   at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:39)
   at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:616)
   at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:140)
   at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1220)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:513)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:448)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.jetty.JettyLauncher$WebAppContextWithReload.doStart(JettyLauncher.java:468)
at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:39)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.RequestLogHandler.doStart(RequestLogHandler.java:115)
at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:39)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:222)
at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:39)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.jetty.JettyLauncher.start(JettyLauncher.java:672)
at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.doStartUpServer(DevMode.java:509)
at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.startUp(DevModeBase.java:1093)
at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.run(DevModeBase.java:836)
at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.main(DevMode.java:311)
   Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating  bean with name 'hibernateTemplate' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to get the default Bean Validation factory
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:329)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:107)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1387)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1128)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:628)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
at org.springframework.web.context.support.AbstractRefreshableWebApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractRefreshableWebApplicationContext.java:134)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:246)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:184)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderServlet.init(ContextLoaderServlet.java:83)
at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:212)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:433)
... 20 more
   Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to get the default Bean Validation factory
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1482)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:323)
... 38 more
   Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to get the default Bean   Validation factory
at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.BeanValidationActivator.applyDDL(BeanValidationActivator.java:127)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.applyBeanValidationConstraintsOnDDL(Configuration.java:1704)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.applyConstraintsToDDL(Configuration.java:1654)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1445)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildMappings(Configuration.java:1375)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:720)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.AbstractSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractSessionFactoryBean.java:188)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1541)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1479)
... 45 more
    Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.BeanValidationActivator.applyDDL(BeanValidationActivator.java:118)
... 53 more
    Caused by: org.hibernate.AssertionFailure: Entity class not found
at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.TypeSafeActivator.applyDDL(TypeSafeActivator.java:124)
... 58 more
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.test.shared.User
at java.lang.ClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:352)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:337)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
at org.hibernate.util.ReflectHelper.classForName(ReflectHelper.java:170)
at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.TypeSafeActivator.applyDDL(TypeSafeActivator.java:121)
... 58 more
```

Note: I am not using maven. I downloaded the jars and included them in the build path.

Comment: Where you are injecting validationFactory bean? As per Your code sessionFactory not depending on validationFactory.

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 options:

1.- You could disable the Hibernate Validation:

```
setProperty("javax.persistence.validation.mode", "NONE");
```

2.- Add these dependencies, if you don't use maven then download the jars and add to your artifact manually:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.el-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.4</version>
        <scope>provided</scope> <!-- No required in JBoss but for test -->
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.el</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.4</version>
        <scope>provided</scope> <!-- No required in JBoss but for test -->
    </dependency>
```